# Cells of equal width using tabular

Tags: tables, fontspec

Is it possible to give these cells the same width as the widest in the first row (κεῖσθαι?)? (keeping the text centered). The leftmost cells should be allowed to be wider.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Junicode}

\begin{document}
  \vskip.5\baselineskip
  {\tiny\noindent
  \begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    & οὐσία & ποσὸν & ποιὸν & πρός τι & ποὺ & ποτὲ &
  κεῖσθαι & ἔχειν & ποιεῖν & πάσχειν\\ \hline
    ἐντελεχείᾳ&&&&&&&&&&\\ \hline
    δυνάμει&&&&&&&&&&\\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
  }\vskip.5\baselineskip
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This gives left alignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Unless I'm mistaken `πάσχειν` is ever so slightly wider than `κεῖσθαι` -- at least if the `Junicode` font is in use.)

In the preamble of the following example, a length variable named `\mylen` is set up, and its value is set to the value of `{\tiny πάσχειν}`. Then, a new columntype, named `C`, is defined, which takes a fixed width (viz., `\mylen`) and centers its contents. Finally, the `tabular` environment is set up with 1 column of type `c` and 10 columns of type `C`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Junicode}

\usepackage{array} % for \newcolumntype and \arraybackslash macros
\newlength\mylen
\settowidth\mylen{\tiny πάσχειν}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\mylen}}

\begin{document}

  {\tiny\noindent
  \begin{tabular}{|c|*{10}{C|}}
  \hline
  & οὐσία & ποσὸν & ποιὸν & πρός τι & ποὺ & ποτὲ & κεῖσθαι & ἔχειν & ποιεῖν & πάσχειν\\ \hline
  ἐντελεχείᾳ&&&&&&&&&&\\ \hline
  δυνάμει&&&&&&&&&&\\ \hline
  \end{tabular} \par}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `tabularx`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Junicode}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
  \vskip.5\baselineskip
  {\tiny\noindent
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}*{11}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}@{}|}
      & Οὐσίαn & ποσὸν & ποιὸν & πρός τι & ποὺ & ποτὲ &
      κεῖσθαι & ἔχειν & ποιεῖν & πάσχειν\\ \hline
      ἐντελεχείᾳ&&&&&&&&&&\\ \hline
      δυνάμει&&&&&&&&&&\\ \hline
    \end{tabularx}
  }\vskip.5\baselineskip
\end{document}
```

Comment: This method will make the cells 2 thru 11 quite a bit wider than the OP has asked for.

Answer (score 2):

You can measure each item and then set the header items in a box as wide as the widest item.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
%\usepackage{xparse} % fontspec loads it

\setmainfont{Junicode}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\newenvironment{ftabular}[2][c]
 {
  \lawrence_ftabular:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }
 {
  \endtabular
 }

\tl_new:N \l__lawrence_ftabular_header_tl
\dim_new:N \l__lawrence_ftabular_maxwd_dim
\box_new:N \l__lawrence_ftabular_item_box

\cs_new_protected:Nn \lawrence_ftabular:nn
 {
  \tl_clear:N \l__lawrence_ftabular_header_tl
  \dim_zero:N \l__lawrence_ftabular_maxwd_dim
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #2 }
   {
    \hbox_set:Nn \l__lawrence_ftabular_item_box { ##1 }
    \dim_set:Nn \l__lawrence_ftabular_maxwd_dim
     {
      \dim_max:nn
       { \l__lawrence_ftabular_maxwd_dim }
       { \box_wd:N \l__lawrence_ftabular_item_box }
     }
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l__lawrence_ftabular_header_tl
     { & {\makebox[\l__lawrence_ftabular_maxwd_dim]{##1}} }
   }
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l__lawrence_ftabular_header_tl { \\ \hline }
  \tabular[#1]{ c| *{ \clist_count:n { #2 } } { c| } }
  \tl_use:N \l__lawrence_ftabular_header_tl 
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\tiny
\begin{ftabular}{
  οὐσία,
  ποσὸν,
  ποιὸν,
  πρός τι,
  ποὺ,
  ποτὲ,
  κεῖσθαι,
  ἔχειν,
  ποιεῖν,
  πάσχειν,
}
ἐντελεχείᾳ&&&&&&&&&&\\ \hline
δυνάμει&&&&&&&&&&\\ \hline
\end{ftabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that the current font will be used for measuring. For instance, if I add, after `\end{center}`, the code

```
\LARGE

\begin{ftabular}{a,bb,cccc,d}
x&&&&\\\hline
y&&&&\\\hline
\end{ftabular}
```

I get the following output

[image]